# How to plot 3 plots simultaneously in one plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot 3 datasets in 1 graph so that I can compare them.

```
dataset2.plot(kind='scatter',x='time',y='Temp')

dataset27.plot(kind='scatter',x='teime1',y='Temp1')

dataset28.plot(kind='scatter',x='time2',y='Temp2')
```

Please Help.

Comment: did you try subplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) on what parameters you can set with `df.plot()`

You need to create 3 subplots and plot to those subplots. For example, one way you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4)) #create a figure with a 12 width, 4 length

ax1 = plt.subplot(131) #subplot with 1 row, 3 columns the 1st one
ax2 = plt.subplot(132) #subplot with 1 row, 3 columns the 2nd one
ax3 = plt.subplot(133) #subplot with 1 row, 3 columns the 3rd one


dataset2.plot(kind='scatter',x='time',y='Temp',ax=ax1)
dataset27.plot(kind='scatter',x='teime1',y='Temp1',ax=ax2)
dataset28.plot(kind='scatter',x='time2',y='Temp2',ax=ax3)

plt.show()
```

To plot them all over each other:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111) #1 subplot

dataset2.plot(kind='scatter',x='time',y='Temp',ax=ax)
dataset27.plot(kind='scatter',x='teime1',y='Temp1',ax=ax)
dataset28.plot(kind='scatter',x='time2',y='Temp2',ax=ax)
```

Comment: Sir i want to plot all 3 data in One graph not 3 different graph in same window.

Comment: Then plot to the same axes